# proc tabulate get `sumproduct` result

Tags: sas, proc

data looks like

```
TM  a  b  c
A   1  2  0.5
B   2  5  0.4
```

ideal output is

```
TM  c
A   0.5
B   0.4
All 3/7
```

I tried `pctsum` in `proc tabulate`. But it doesn't work in the way I expected.

```
proc tabulate data = dat;
class TM;
var a b c;
table (TM='' all), (c * pctsum<b>='' * f=5.1);
run;
```

Comment: What is the output look like with your code? Is it the first three lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gathering that you want your total to be the mean of column C, weighted by column B. Use `c * mean` in your table statement and add a `weight` statement. You won't be able to show the total as a fraction, but you can increase the number of decimals in your format:

```
proc tabulate data = dat;
class TM;
var a b c;
table (TM='' all), (c * mean='' * f=5.3);
weight b;
run;
```

New option: For different weights on different variables, use multiple `var` statements and add a `weight=` option to each one:

```
proc tabulate data = dat;
class TM;
var b / weight=a;
var c / weight=b;
table (TM='' all), (c * mean='' * f=5.3)
                   (b * mean='' * f=5.3);
run;
```

Comment: Can I assign different `weight` to different variable listed in `var`? e.g. output both `sum(b*c)/sum(b)` and `sum(d*a)/sum(a)` ? (assume I have more than a, b, c in `var`)

Comment: Added example to answer.

Comment: In your second example, `weight b` on top of `run;` can be removed?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to take that out.

Comment: Actually, you can get the fraction, if you want: [FRACTw.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0hr5u6qwmp0wyn1tmp92v0ubgyc.htm) format.